# How to get prefix properties using @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="foo.bar") without using @PropertySources annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to read properties in my spring-boot application. I want to read all properties with prefix 'foo.bar'

I have tried below code and it is working fine.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(" file:${property.location}/somefile.properties") })
public class SomeClass{
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.bar")
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return new Properties();
    }
}
```

But now because of some restrictions I don't want to use **@PropertySource** and I'm expecting same result as above for my prefix-properties.
Instead of @PropertySource , now I'm using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  to load the properties as in below code-

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer pC = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new 
              PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(some-path);
     pC.setLocations(array);
     return pC;
}
```

Please suggest if there is a way to load these prefix-properties without using @PropertySource?

Comment: Just add `spring.config.additional-locations` to add the file to load. Adding a new `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` will lead to problems and won't make the properties available in the `Environment` which eventually is used to resolve the values.

Comment: I have several properties files and few of them needs to be loaded in an specified order and I'm not allowed to hard-code these properties filenames in my Java file with @PropertySource. So it left me no other choice but to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: Again read my comment. You can specify as much property files as you want with `spring.config.additional-locations`. Spring Boot has already everything in place you need, work with the framework instead of hacking around it.

Comment: And if multiple files are specified, in what order these file will be picked? How can I maintain an specific ordering of these files?

Comment: They are loaded in the order specified and they are all part of the `Environment` and follow the rules as described in the Spring Boot reference guide regarding externalizing configuration.